# C++ application build time/date saving

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I know that in NetBeans and Visial you can somehow statically save the date and build time of your app. I'm building some software on a remote server with the g++ and I wonder if there is a way of creating for example something like this:

```
#define BUIL_DATE <here should be the compilation date>
```

That I could use later on in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` (GCC-specific) macros are what you're looking for.  For example:

```
#define BUILDSTAMP ( __DATE__ " " __TIME__ )
```

See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: @Evilgreed: no problem.  Just mark the answer if you're done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#define BUIL_DATE                                                           \
    do {                                                                    \
        std::cout << " compiled on " __DATE__ " : " __TIME__ << "\n";       \
    } while (0)


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BUIL_DATE;  
    return 0;
}
```